# Powershell capturing group in pipeline select-object with calculated property

Tags: powershell

Given the following **input** XML sample -- assume multiple LogMessage entries.

```
<LogMessages>
    <LogMessage time="2017-12-08 11:44:05.202" messageID="A10">
        <![CDATA[Long non-xml string here containing <TS "2017120811431218"> somewhere in the body"]>
    </LogMessage>
</LogMessages>
```

I am using the following code to capture the values of attributes *time*, *messageID*, and capture a group in the CDATA.

```
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content input.xml
$xml.LogMessages.LogMessage | Where-Object {$_.messageID -eq "A10"}  | Select-Object -Property time,messageID,@{Name="A10Timestamp"; Expression=$_."#cdata-section" -match '<TS "(?<group>[0-9]{16})">'  | Select-Object $Matches['group'] }}   `
    | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output** looks like:

```
time                    messageID Group     
----                    --------- ---------------     
2017-12-08 11:43:12.183 S6F1      @{2017120811431218=}
```

The @{ and } wrapping the captured group value is undesired. I am concerned about this particular use of the $Matches variable...I think what gets printed is a Match object and not the group string that it matched on... or something like this.

What is going on and how do I get the entries in the *Group* column appear as *2017120811431218* and not *@{2017120811431218=}*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#-match) operator returns a boolean and populates the `$Matches` variable with the matching results.
In other words, you should void what is returned by the `-Match` operator (and not pipe it) and than simply return the `$Matches['group']` to the `Expression`:

```
Expression={$Void = $_."#cdata-section" -match '<TS "(?<group>[0-9]{16})">'; $Matches['group']}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a great deal.